# Prestige Points after starting MW3

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

Can I earn an extra point if you prestige in MW2 *after* you have already prestiged in MW3? I did and dont see the PP

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get a prestige token in Modern Warfare 3, if you prestige in Modern Warfare 2, even now.  Note that you can only get one prestige token *per game* - so if this was your second (or third, etc) prestige in MW2, you won't get another token for it.

Sometimes it can take some time for the point to show up; sometimes you'll want to log out and log back in, or wait a day in order to see the new token if you earned one.  If you're still having issues, the best thing to do is to post on the [Modern Warfare 3 forums](http://www.callofduty.com/community/mw3/forums) for support.